# Custom profile User doesnt have access for Record sharing

Tags: sharing, role-hierarchy

I have a custom profile 'System Administrator1' and only one user under this profile
and that user is not able to share account records with the users who are below them in the role hierarchy

When user is trying record shring, getting this error in lightning experience, but the user is able to share the records in Classic
But we are not using classic.

In profile level, there is 'Transfer record' permission

Error on record sharing

[image]

Please help me on this..thanksin advance

Comment: Does the user whom you are trying to share record have account object access ?

Comment: yes..read, edit, view all, modify all, all permissions are there

Comment: If the record has view all then why is it needed to share.

Comment: this user want to share this account record to some users

Comment: Yeah got it. Does the other user have access for Account object?

Comment: yes have read, create and edit permission

Comment: i SOLVED IT, IN LIGHTNING THEY WERE USING A CUSTOM SHARING BUTTON AND IT WAS NOT WORKING. I replaced that with standard sharing button